# Django passing kwargs to inherited form causes error (generic UpdateView)

Tags: python, django, forms, generics

When I use django generic view - UpdateView and try to update form kwargs like this:

```
#views.py

from .forms import SomeInheritedForm
from .models import SomeModel

from django.views.generic import UpdateView

class SomeUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = SomeModel
    form_class = SomeInheritedForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(SomeUpdateView, self).get_form_kwargs(**kwargs)
        kwargs['workspace'] = 'whatever'
        return kwargs

#forms.py

from .models import SomeModel

from django import forms

class ParentForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.workspace = kwargs.pop('workspace', None)
        super(ParentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class InheritedForm(forms.ModelForm, ParentForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
```

This will give such an error:

```
Django Version: 1.7.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'workspace'
Exception Location: /[ommited]/my_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py in get_form, line 45
Python Executable:  /[ommited]/my_venv/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
```

However, if I declare `__init__` in InheritedForm it will work fine. But then, with more inherited forms I would have to copy the code, which is against DRY principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python always tries to find methods via the MRO, which is based on the order the parent classes are declared. So in this case since you put `ModelForm` first in the class definition, it will find the `__init__` there first, hence the error.

The solution is just to swap the order:

```
class InheritedForm(ParentForm, forms.ModelForm):
```

although I do wonder why you've declared ParentForm as inheriting from forms.Form in the first place - might as well make it inherit from ModelForm, then you don't need the multiple inheritance in InheritedForm.

Comment: This way, I won't have access to model fields in `ParentForm.__init__`, which I need in final work. 
However changing `forms.Form` to `forms.ModelForm` in `ParentForm` (and removing it from `InheritedForm`) solved the problem. Thanks!